# Checkbox should be checked if the value is true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

This is my code. I wanted to show my checkboxes if the value is true there should be check. But instead I'm getting an error saying:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

```
@foreach($benefits as $benefit)
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="benefit[]">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$benefit->id}}" id="benefit_id" name="benefit_id[]" @if($benefit->id == $user->benefits->id) checked @endif>{{$benefit->name}}
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: show us your user to benefits relationship

Comment: Please show results of `{{ dd($benefits, $user->benefits) }}`

Comment: for user model this is the relationship "    public function benefits()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Vanguard\Models\Benefits', 'users_benefits', 'user_id', 'benefit_id');
    } "

Comment: theres none in the Benefits model

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose `$user->benefits` is a collection that contains multiple `Benefit` objects. You cannot just get a property of a collection, you need to check if any object in that collection has an `id` property that equals the current `id`.

A possible solution could be using the [`contains`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-contains) function on Laravel collections. This function will check if an object exists with the given value for a certain key.

```
@if($user->benefits->contains('id', $benefit->id)) checked @endif
```

An even nicer solution in blade would be

```
{{ $user->benefits->contains('id', $benefit->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

Comment: @gwapo you should choose this answer as the best one.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin okay sir